# how to convert localDateTime to string date DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: java, localdatetime

I have data `localDateTime` in java like this

```java
localDateTime localDateTime = 2022-01-04 14:59:20.207;
```

How to convert it to format `DD/MM/YYYY` ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` has a method for that, it's called `.format(DateTimeFormatter)`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "2022-01-04 14:59:20.207".replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
.toLocalDate()
.format ( 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )
    .withLocale( Locale.FRANCE )
)
```

## Details

Parse your input string. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with the ISO 8601 standard format.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-01-04 14:59:20.207".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

Extract a date.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generally best to automatically localize rather than hard-code a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.FRANCE ) ;
String output = ld.format ( f ) ;
```

> 04/01/2022

Or hard-code a specific formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
```